# How to get state vector from QasmSimulator in Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, programming

I'm currently able to get state vector in Qiskit using state_vector backend using something like :

```
backend = Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')
job = execute(qc, backend=backend, shots=1, memory=True)
job_result = job.result()
print(job_result.get_statevector(qc))
```

But now I would like to get state vector using qasm_backend, I have seen in the Qiskit doc this sample code :

```
backend = QasmSimulator()
backend_options = {"method": "statevector"}

# Circuit execution
job = execute(qc, backend, backend_options=backend_options)
```

So I tried this backend implementation then trying to get state vector with :

```
job_result = job.result()
print(job_result.get_statevector(qc))
```

But it still gives me an error saying that get_statevector is not available, what is the right way to do that ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using the `QasmSimulator` class from Aer it does not generate a state vector result. The `statevector` method you passed in as a backend option is the simulation method/technique that Aer will use for simulating the circuit, but it is still the QASM simulator which is expected to return measurement counts not a statevector. You can see a description of the different simulation methods in the [`QasmSimulator` Docs](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.aer.QasmSimulator.html#qiskit.providers.aer.QasmSimulator).

When you were calling `Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')` that returns a [`StateVectorSimulator`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.aer.StatevectorSimulator.html#qiskit.providers.aer.StatevectorSimulator) backend object which will simulate the circuit and return the state vector at the end of the execution and return that in the result, which is why `get_statevector` works there. If you want to get the state vector while using the `QasmSimulator` you can use the [`SnapshotStatevector`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.aer.extensions.SnapshotStatevector.html#qiskit.providers.aer.extensions.SnapshotStatevector) instruction in your circuit which will return the state vector at that point in the circuit. Although, if you do this the state vector won't be returned by `get_statevector` (that will still fail) it will be in the snapshots under [`Result.data`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.result.Result.html?highlight=result%20result%20data#qiskit.result.Result.data).

Comment: To insert a snapshot instruction: `circ.snapshot_statevector('snapshot_label')` (this will add a snapshot whose label is "snapshot_label", you can assign any string as a label name).

Comment: This requires to import the instruction:  `from qiskit.providers.aer.extensions.snapshot_statevector import *`

Comment: Thank you, it is what I was looking for !

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Qiskit v0.9 or higher, then `snapshot_statevector` has been superseded by the `save_statevector` circuit method. So you can use your initial code but need to just save the statevector at some point:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, execute
from qiskit.providers.aer import QasmSimulator

qc = QuantumCircuit(2,2)
qc.h(0)
qc.cx(0,1)
qc.save_statevector()

backend = QasmSimulator()
backend_options = {'method': 'statevector'}
job = execute(qc, backend, backend_options=backend_options)
job_result = job.result()
print(job_result.get_statevector(qc))
```

If you need to save statevector at multiple places, then the result must be read from `result.data(0)[]`, `result.get_statevector` won't work here:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, execute
from qiskit.providers.aer import QasmSimulator

qc = QuantumCircuit(2,2)
qc.h(0)
qc.save_statevector(label='v1')
qc.cx(0,1)
qc.save_statevector(label='v2')

backend = QasmSimulator()
backend_options = {'method': 'statevector'}
job = execute(qc, backend, backend_options=backend_options)
result = job.result()
sv1 = result.data(0)['v1']
sv2 = result.data(0)['v2']
print('Statevector 1', sv1)
print('Statevector 2', sv2)
```

There is also a very handy set of operations in `qiskit.quantum_info`, that allows to get and display the statevectors:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, execute
from qiskit.providers.aer import QasmSimulator
import qiskit.quantum_info as qi

qc = QuantumCircuit(2,2)
qc.h(0)
qc.cx(0,1)
stv1 = qi.Statevector.from_instruction(qc)

sim = QasmSimulator()
options = {'method': 'statevector'}
execute(qc, sim, backend_options=options)

stv1.draw('latex', prefix='Statevector1:')
```

This way you can get a nicely formatted result:

Statevector1:
\begin{bmatrix}
\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & 0 & \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \\
 \end{bmatrix}